# html form regex pattern validation

Tags: regex, html, validation

I have been searching google for some time but cannot get my html pattern validation to work correctly :(

I have 2 phone fields in my form - home and mobile - which I am trying to use `pattern=""` to validate. However the regex is difficult and I don't really understand how this works.

The requirements are as follows:

A mobile phone number number should:

- begin with 07.
- be 10 or 11 characters in length
- not begin with 070 or 076

Home phone numbers must only begin with 01 or 02 or 03.

Comment: So far I have pattern="^07[\d]{10,12}" - not sure how to exclude the 070 or 076 yet

Answer (score 0):

Mobile phones: `07[12345789]\d{7,8}`

Home phones: `(01|02|03)\d+`

If there are the same length restrictions for home phones, then instead of `\d+` you have to use `\d{8,9}`